# Ubuntu has frozen on me

Tags: boot

I just built my own computer and installed ubuntu but when i reset my computer and took out the cd when it started up alls that happened is a purple screen appeared and nothing happens when i hit any of the keys. except for when i move my mouse all the way up the screen then i get a white and purple striped screen.

Comment: Hi, welcome to askubuntu! Please add more info about your computer (brand and hardware) as well as the ubuntu version you're trying to install; ie. 12.04 Desktop 64bit, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with one of my older servers when I changed the graphics borad.

Your problem is almost certainly due to the graphics hardware. If you start your PC with the CD and it comes up fine then that confirms that the PC is OK but the graphics driver must be updated.

Restart the PC without the CD which will give you the dead screen. Cut the power and start again but be prepared to hit the down arrow key as soon as the boot options screen shows up. Choose the fail safe startup to get the PC up and runing with basic graphics.

Find the icon for additional hardware (look like a circuitboard) and update the graphics driver. You will probably have to accept a driver from the graphics board maker but at least its free.

Once updated you can restart and adjust the graphics resolution.

Don't give up.

PS. You will need an Internet connection for the update to run automatically. Ohterwise download the makers driver and install manually.